# I'm running Lubuntu 18.04 and my laptop isn't getting internet access even after being connected to a network

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, internet

no matter which wifi i connect it to, there is no internet access, even USB tethering isnt working. Please help me out

(Dell Inspiron 3180)

Comment: Could you provide the results of `lspci -nnk | grep -A 5 Network`, `ifconfig`, and `rfkill list`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Y3BAuiVx

Comment: I assume [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Lubuntu/comments/cj6k1z/my_lubuntu_1804_is_connected_to_the_wifi_but/evegb4e/?st=jyxeaoyo&sh=b4fb2350) is you? If so, I'd pick one or the other place to discuss this.

Comment: yeah that's me, I prefer Reddit, could you DM me/ comment on that list on Reddit to discuss it? it would help a lot I'm really struggling here

Comment: Then you've got comments there to reply to.